# Build an array of matching links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays, string

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to "exctract" from a *string* (or a *text*) all links present in that.

At this time I have the following regex* in order to match URL and e-mail addresses:

```
/((\S+)?(@|mailto\:)|((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)|([www]))\S+/
```

If I have the following *string*:

```
text here http://www.sitename.com and text here www.sitename.com and text here email@sitename.com and text here
```

I would like to get an array (or some other data structure) populated of links present in the above string.

**How can I do?**

---

**BTW*: Is the regex "good" enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
text = 'text here http://www.sitename.com and text here www.sitename.com and text here email@sitename.com and text here'
links = []
text.split.each do |word|
  links << word if word.match(/(((\S+)?)((@|mailto\:)|(((ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/)|([www]))\S+)/)
end
puts links
```